# Problema com Player no celular - app webview

Tags: javascript, java, html, android

Eu criei um app no webView e o player dele só funciona quando apertamos o botão play 3 vezes ( uma para reproduzir o video, depois pausar e depois aperta novamente ele toca o video )

o link do app para demonstrar o erro: 
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B3xCH5qpmt1vVHl1enhkSVJrYjQ

porém  o erro é somente no celular, ele no pc funciona perfeitamente.
A PÁGINA É ESSA:
http://pipocaplayfm.com/mobile-play/

O código do webview - `MainActivity.java`:

```
package com.creator.music;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.animation.TranslateAnimation;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebSettings.RenderPriority;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    // set your custom url here
    String url = " http://EU INSIRO A URL AKI";
    boolean doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = false;

    // if you want to show progress bar on splash screen
    Boolean showProgressOnSplashScreen = true;

    WebView mWebView;
    ProgressBar prgs;
    RelativeLayout splash, main_layout;


    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS, Window.PROGRESS_VISIBILITY_ON);
        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wv);
        prgs = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        main_layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_layout);

        // splash screen View

        if (!showProgressOnSplashScreen)
            ((ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBarSplash)).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        splash = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.splash);

//      if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
//
//          // get status bar height to push webview below that
//          int result = 0;
//          int resourceId = getResources().getIdentifier("status_bar_height",
//                  "dimen", "android");
//          if (resourceId > 0) {
//              result = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(resourceId);
//          }
//
//          // set top padding to status bar
//          main_layout.setPadding(0, result, 0, 0);
//      }

        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) this.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (activeNetwork != null && activeNetwork.isConnected()) {

            mWebView.loadUrl(url);
            Toast.makeText(this,"Recommended to use 3G/4G or Wifi ",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            // control javaScript and add html5 features
            mWebView.setFocusable(true);
            mWebView.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
            mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            mWebView.getSettings().setRenderPriority(RenderPriority.HIGH);
            mWebView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
            mWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
            mWebView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
            mWebView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
            mWebView.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
            mWebView.getSettings().setDatabasePath(
                    this.getFilesDir().getPath() + this.getPackageName()
                            + "/databases/");

            // this force use chromeWebClient
            mWebView.getSettings().setSupportMultipleWindows(true);


            mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

                @Override
                public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                    view.loadUrl(url);
                    return false;
                }

                @Override
                public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                    super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
                    if (prgs.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
                        prgs.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onLoadResource(WebView view, String url) {
                    super.onLoadResource(view, url);
                }

                @Override
                public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                    super.onPageFinished(view, url);

                    if (prgs.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE)
                        prgs.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                    // check if splash is still there, get it away!
                    if (splash.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE)
                        splash.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    slideToBottom(splash);

                }

            });

        }
        else{

            //Toast.makeText(this,"Your Device is not connected to Internet , Please Turn ON Data Services",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setTitle("Error");
            builder.setMessage("No Network Connection").setCancelable(false)
                    .setIcon(R.drawable.logo)
                    .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            finish();
                        }
                    });
            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();

            Toast.makeText(this,"Your Device is not connected to Internet , Recommended to use 3G/4G or Wifi ",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }

    }




    /**
     * To animate view slide out from top to bottom
     *
     *
     */
    void slideToBottom(View view) {
        TranslateAnimation animate = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, 0,
                view.getHeight());
        animate.setDuration(2000);
        animate.setFillAfter(true);
        view.startAnimation(animate);
        view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    /*@Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(final int keyCode, final KeyEvent event) {
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && mWebView.canGoBack()) {
            mWebView.goBack();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }*/
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (doubleBackToExitPressedOnce) {
            super.onBackPressed();
            return;
        }

        this.doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = true;
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please click BACK again to exit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                doubleBackToExitPressedOnce=false;
            }
        }, 2000);
    }

}
```

'

Comment: Então o App carrega uma página dentro do WebView? Pode postar o link da página ou código do player?

Comment: isso ...webview .
eu percebi que para o player funcionar eu tenho que apertar 3 vezes - uma para iniciar ,depois pausar, depois iniciar novamente. 

a pagina que abre é essa http://pipocaplayfm.com/mobile-play/

Comment: No navegador aqui funcionou normal. Você habilitou o JavaScript para o WebView? `WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings(); webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);`

Comment: @CarlosAndrade eu vou publicar o MainActivity.java na pergunta

Comment: @CarlosAndrade navegador no celular ? qual navegador ? no Mozilla ele funciona , agora nos outros não funciona perfeito.

Answer (score 0):

Tanto no webview como nos navegadores de dispositivos móveis, o som não pode ser iniciado automaticamente, ele precisa de uma ação do usuário para começar a tocar, como apertar um botão por exemplo. Assim, o que você tem que arrumar no seu javascript é para ele não tocar automaticamente (essa função só vai funcionar se usar um PC). Assim o usuário vai abrir a página, clicar no play e funcionar. Caso o autoplay esteja ativado, o usuário terá que clicar para pausar e depois clicar novamente para começar a tocar, gerando a situação do seu problema atual.

Comment: Você não precisa mexer em nada no seu Android Studio. E sim no javascript do seu site.

Comment: Porem eu desabilitando ele , as pessoas quando estiver ouvindo alguns ou playlists vão ter que clicar toda vez na música ?por ter essa função desativada

Comment: Provavelmente a playlist não pode ser usada no celular, pois o som teria que ser iniciado automaticamente, o que não é possível. A cada mudança de música a pessoa terá que clicar no play para ouvir.

Comment: Com certeza deve haver métodos para contornar essa questão do AutoPlay, há muitos aplicativos que funcionam passando as faixas automaticamente, como por ex: Spotify

Comment: Não quero ser desanimador. Mas se você quiser continuar usando o webview é improvável que o autoplay funcione, pois é uma configuração no  webview que não permite isso. Pessoal usava uns hacks no passado para isso funcionar, mas nada estável. O Spotify é um aplicativo nativo e não usa webview. Você pode tentar alguma alternativa mais robusta para aplicativos híbridos como o phonegap, assim terá mais controle do dispositivo e poderá usar e abusar do HTML5.  Você pode, também, desenvolver 100% do seu projeto no Android Studio, ai terá mais controle da aplicação. Abraço.